# MVC 4 Passing model from one controller to view and from view to other controller without users able to edit all fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Im kinda new in MVC4 and im not able to figure it out.

```
              "CustomViewMOdel"        "CustomViewMOdel"
"ControllerX" ----------------> "VIEW" -----------------> "ControllerY"
```

My problem is that i want to pass my customviewmodel to view (which is working just fine!). In the View im showing some of model's fields to users (which is working fine also). BUT Now i want user, to change ONE field of the models fields and then PASS the WHOLE model to Controller X (with all fields filled, including the field what user was able to change AND other fields what were just shown)

Can anyone give a very simple code example of how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a form that posts to another controller:

ControllerX:

```
public ActionResult DoSomething()
{
     return View(new CustomVM());
}
```

ViewA

```
@Model CustomViewModel

@using Html.BeginForm("DoSomethingElse", "ControllerY")
{
    @Html.EditorFor(vm => vm.SomeProperty)
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

ControllerY

```
public ActionResult DoSomethingElse(CustomViewModel vm)
{
    // do something else
}
```

Comment: I have a lot of fields that i want on show to users, but not allow to change them, there i use DisplayFor(). 
And for the changeable field "DropdownProperty" i use dropdownlistFor().
When i debug in controllerY i can see, that  in my CustomViewModel there are only "DropdownProperty" value , all the other values are null. 
I tryed to use html.hidden for but it isnt working, my CostuomViewModel properties (beside "DropDownProperty") are still null.

Comment: If you also want to post those, then you need `Html.HiddenFor`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Html.HiddenFor(o => o.Property)` on the form.
This will not show a property on it.
But the advanced user may change the property through a development console. So you should check all the changes in the ControllerY

Example:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(o => o.Id)
@Html.HiddenFor(o => o.Name)
@Html.EditorFor(o => o.Description)

<input type="submit" value="OK" />
```

This will only let the user change a description but still have "id" and "name" on the FormCollection.

Comment: In Controller Y it will still show that CustomViewModel property values are null, beside that property what user have changed.

Comment: You should have a default constructor in your CustomViewModel like 'public CustomViewModel() {}' to auto-accept a model from view to controller

Comment: Or you can try to accept "FormCollection collection" property in ControllerY and check this properties. Example: http://stack247.wordpress.com/2011/03/20/get-forms-post-values-in-asp-net-mvc-with-formcollection/